# Can't use get_FOO_display with multiple level tuple

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.6 and I have to make a choice field (for which I use models.IntegerField) with choices that look like this:

```
# models.py
REPERTORY_CATEGORIES = (
    ('Whatever', (
        (1, 'Whatever'),
        (2, 'Whatever'),
        (3, 'Whatever'),
        (4, 'Whatever')
    )
), ('Whatever', (
        (5, 'Whatever'),
        (6, 'Whatever'),
        (8, 'Whatever'),
        (9, 'Whatever'),
        (10, 'Whatever'),
        (11, 'Whatever')
    )
)
```

Then when I try to show the field in admin, I use this:

```
# admin.py
list_display = ("title", 'get_repertory_category_display',)
```

But the column name shows as "curried" and the value is the number. Problem is, I must have multiple levels so the client can easily see all his categories and subcategories easily.

Here's the models I use:

```
class BaseLinks(Displayable):
    website = models.CharField(verbose_name="URL du lien", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    search_fields = ['title']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

class RepertoryLinks(BaseLinks):

    # List of categories
    REPERTORY_CATEGORIES = (
        ('Whatever', (
            (1, 'Whatever'),
            (2, 'Whatever'),
            (3, 'Whatever'),
            (4, 'Whatever')
        )
    ), ('Whatever', (
            (5, 'Whatever'),
            (6, 'Whatever'),
            (8, 'Whatever'),
            (9, 'Whatever'),
            (10, 'Whatever'),
            (11, 'Whatever')
        )
    )

    excerpt = RichTextField(verbose_name="Bref résumé des services offerts ou de la mission de l'organisation",
                            null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name="Adresse", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name="Ville", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(verbose_name="Code Postal", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(verbose_name="Téléphone", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(verbose_name="Télécopieur", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    contactname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Personne ressource", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Courriel", max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    ik_image = FileField("Image", max_length=200, upload_to="", blank=True, null=True)
    repertory_category = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Catégorie de Répertoire", max_length=255, choices=REPERTORY_CATEGORIES)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: Model was added, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'repertory_category'` in `list_display` instead of `'get_repertory_category_display'`.

```
list_display = ("title", "repertory_category",)
```

Comment: When I do this, the column name is good, but there is no value anywhere, most probably because the id is not at the tuples root.

Comment: Does it work if you don't have the multiple levels in your choices? I'd be surprised if that's the problem, because it's a supported way to do [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices).